# Error when integrate Stripe PayNow on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

i still new about reactJS and i want to integrate Stripe PayNow payment method on it. here is the tutorial from Stripe [Stripe PayNow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/paynow/accept-a-payment?platform=web#confirm-payment-intent) this tutorial share code on frontend use HTML and Javascript. However, i want to convert the code to reactJS but i got error..

here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; 
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

  function PaymentPaynow(props) {
   
    //STRIPE PAYNOW
    var response = fetch('/create-payment-intent-paynow').then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(responseJson) {
        var clientSecret = responseJson.client_secret;
        // Call stripe.confirmPayNowPayment() with the client secret.
    });
 
    var stripePaynow = loadStripe('pk_test_.....');

    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form-paynow');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Set the clientSecret here you got in Step 2
        stripePaynow.confirmPayNowPayment(
        clientSecret,
        ).then((res) => {
            if(res.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                // The user scanned the QR code
            } else {
                // The user closed the modal, cancelling payment
            }
        });
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs"> 
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link " >PayNow</a>
                </li> 
            </ul>  

            <form id="payment-form-paynow">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" ></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PaymentPaynow;
```

but i got this error [image]

Please help. How do i can resolve this.

Comment: Stripe already has an implementation for React. Have a look at the documentation here I think it will be quite helpful https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react

Comment: Also here's a working example to view https://codesandbox.io/s/omfb3

Comment: thank you for the reply i need to integrate 2 payment methods. CC and paynow. for i already implemented CC payment but struggle integrate PayNow.